Appium Solve Slider Captcha
Please help me solve the Slider Captcha using Appium and Java. I'm stuck when trying to solve it with input distance from an external provider. Thank you so much:
 public static void slide(AndroidDriver driver, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
        final PointerInput finger      = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence           dragAndDrop = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        // Move finger to the start position
        dragAndDrop.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), startX, startY));
        dragAndDrop.addAction(new Pause(finger, Duration.ofMillis(50)));
        // Press down
        dragAndDrop.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        // Move finger to the end position
        dragAndDrop.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(721), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), endX, endY));
        // Release finger
        dragAndDrop.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        // Perform the actions
        driver.perform(List.of(dragAndDrop));
    }

Captcha Image
I tried multiple times, but the captcha keeps looping.

By "solve captcha" you mean defeat? Why? It seems to be doing its job. If you have a legit reason to be exempt from it, present that reason to whoever has put it up.
